# What are the internal categories in an endofunctor category

Tags: ct.category-theory

Take a category $C$, and take all endofunctors of $C$, so the set $E= \{ M| M: C \rightarrow C \}$.  $E$ forms the objects of a category with morphisms given by all natural transformations $\mu : M \rightarrow N$ for $M,N \in E$.  Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the endofunctor category as defined.  What are the internal categories in $\mathcal{C}$?

Further suppose $C$ is a symmetric monoidal dagger category, in this case, what are the internal categories in $\mathcal{C}$?

Edit:  There has been some talk about adding structure to $[C,C]$.  My original attempt to answer this question was based [on this work](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category+in+a+monoidal+category).  So, let us suppose $E$ has a monoidal structure given by functor compostion.  What can we say then about $Cat[C,C]$.  My last attempts to answer this question focused on functors that were exact.  What if we restrict $[C,C]$ to the exact functors?

Comment: Do you want $C$ to have finite limits (so it is cartesian together with $E$, and composition of internal categories as a map from the pullback of source versus target), or instead $E$ to be monoidal wrt composition (I bet internal monoids here are pretty strange animals)?

Comment: @FoscoLoregian: Internal monoids in $[C,C]$ w.r.t. composition are just monads on $C$ — very familiar and friendly animals!  But yes, as you say, the poster needs to be clear about what sense of “internal categories” they mean: just the general one in any category with finite limits (in which case the answer is a bit boring)? or one of the more elaborate senses, defined in a category with extra structure, in which case they need to explicate what extra structure on $[C,C]$ they have in mind?

Comment: Another thing the OP might have in mind, I guess, is categories *enriched* in $[C,C]$ (with the composition monoidal structure).  These would then be a fairly straightforward generalisation of monads — but it’d be interesting to see examples!

Comment: Of course I wanted to write "internal categories", but somehow overwritten it to "monoids" :-)

Comment: @FoscoLoregian: Ah, OK.  But there again, there’s no standard definition of “internal categories in a monoidal category” (as far as I’m aware): you need to put some more elaborate structure on the ambient category, since internal categories need pullbacks not just products.

Comment: This is precisely what I would have answered to the OP if they would have wanted the composition monoidal structure. I have no idea if it is possible to define internal categories there (I guess: no)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, I have added an edit where we address some additional structure on $[C,C]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I assume here that by “internal category” you mean the usual sense defined in any category with finite limits.)

If $\newcommand{\C}{\textbf{C}}\C$ has finite limits, then for any $\newcommand{\D}{\textbf{D}}\D$, $[\D,\C]$ will have finite limits, constructed as pointwise limits, and so internal categories in $[\D,\C]$ will just be functors from $\D$ into internal categories in $\C$.  So in particular, $\mathrm{Cat}[\C,\C] \simeq [\C,\mathrm{Cat}(\C)]$.